# Rules for from account in Apple Mail

Tags: software-recommendation, mail.app

I happily use mail with several accounts. When I send a new email I often forget to choose the correct 'From' account. Is there a mail plugin that allows to set the default 'From' account using some rules.

One example could be: if the recipient ends in '`@example.com`' use the *work* account.

Or as an alternative is there a way to change the 'From' dropdown menu using a key combination? (this would not solve the case when I forget to set it but would at least speed up the process)

Comment: Are there other mail clients that are more sophisticated and have this feature?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the unified inbox then this can be a problem. If you expand the mailboxes and read them from those, then you can set-up Mail to send using the account for that mailbox.

I suppose this may require remembering to select the correct mailbox in a similar way to remembering to select the from account though.

[image: Composition settings]

Comment: Yes I though about this but as you mention this would lead to the same problem: remembering to choose the correct account :-)

Answer (score 1):

I struggle with the same problems. The answer is that there currently unfortunately is neither a plugin nor a hook for manually solving this problem.

For details look here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/67082/93032

Some workarounds for the problem can be found here: [Mail.app extension to avoid sending email from the wrong account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25618/mail-app-extension-to-avoid-sending-email-from-the-wrong-account)